# Hot to select a region with mouse

Tags: java, image, paint, draw

I want to ask you how I can select-paint a region on java. I have made a project at Netbeans,and I have a background (.GIF) . So, I want to choose a part of this background as I am in Paint and make a circle or square or something like this.
I hope to make it easy for you and you will understand.

For example,if I have this image below,I have the ability to mark the region with the oval.

[image]

Comment: This is like asking us how to make a right turn, without telling us the type of car, where we're making the turn, the traffic laws, etc.

Comment: @hexafraction I gave an example if it can helps you. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a couple of ways to do custom painting. The examples paint on a plain background but there is not reason you couldn't use an Image as the background.

The easiest way to get the background would be to use a JLabel with an ImageIcon and then override the paintComponent() method of the JLabel.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that on mouse down you draw a tiny oval, on mouse move you "unpaint" the old oval you previously drew and draw a new one that is bigger (or smaller, depending on where the mouse has moved to), then on mouse up you make the oval permanent.

So, the trickiest bit is probably how to "unpaint" the previous oval.

For this you can use a high-performance trick known as XOR painting - supposing `g` is a `Graphics2D`:

```
g.setXORMode(Color.red);
```

Though, this was previously used on 1980s microcomputers due to slow painting performance there; it probably isn't necessary on today's PCs. On today's PCs, it might be better to just repaint the background image.

BTW, to detect the mouse events I mentioned, in Java, you will need to use Listeners.